# Alternative of using wifi card for penetration testing

Tags: penetration-test, kali-linux

I want to learn penetration testing on kali linux platform, for that I found that the wifi card is needed. But my question is that, if I install the kali linux as main operating system or make separate partition for kali linux and windows, than also wifi card is needed or not?

Comment: Wifi card have nothing to do with partitions .. ofcourse you'll need one if you want to connect to a wireless network.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you don't want to perform wireless attacks (sniffing, cracking, impersonating an AP,...) you don't need a Wi-Fi card, any kind of NIC will be enough.

For wireless attacks, you clearly need a wireless NIC. This can either be internal, i.e. built-in, or external, i.e. a USB adapter or a PCI Wi-Fi card. Note that if you already have a built-in wireless card supporting promiscuous mode and packet injection you don't need an additional card.

A good list of Wi-Fi cards supported by the Aircrack suite - which is included in Kali as a tool for Wi-Fi attacks - can be found on their own website: http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers&DokuWiki=esblrp5ctfa9d7u2qbpmamndp5#which_is_the_best_card_to_buy.

Comment: how can i check for built-in wireless card?

Comment: can you tell me exactly which wifi card do you use for wireless attacks? Because i'm beginner and confused seeing the huge list of cards which u suggested.

Comment: You need to find the chipset either by reading the specification of your computer (which can be found online) or by using the command line (see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116140/how-can-i-find-out-what-kind-of-wireless-card-i-have-from-output-of-lspci) and find if it is present in the link I wrote in the answer. Product recommendation is usually not accepted in the StackExchange websites. I suggest you to take a look at the USB list and then choose the cheapest adapter and/or the one you can easily find, either in physical shops or online.